# syncing postgres dbs across different accounts and regions

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

**Environment**

- We have 2 `AWS` accounts A and B.
- I have a `postgres` DB on `RDS` in Account B.
- This DB gets updated periodically.
- Few services in Account A need to see the data from DB in Account B.
- We tried using VPN tunnels, however they were not very reliable and kept going down.
- What we thought as an alternative was to create a new `RDS` instance in Account A and get the services to connect to DB in Account A.
- We need to ensure that the data in DB in Account A is updated when the the Account B data gets updated. This does not have to be right away, it can be a nightly task or something like that.

**Questions**

Is it possible to sync 2 `postgres` databases running on `RDS` across different zones and in different accounts ?

- I read up a bit on `Read Replica`, however I am not sure if they work across different accounts.
- The other solution I thought of is to write a script, however I am not sure if I can get only the changes(in B) to be written to the DB in A.

Any other solutions to solve the problem as also welcome.

Thanks

Tanmay

Comment: Did you look at AWS Data Pipeline ?